# PCIe and flow control credits

Tags: linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e, pci-bus

Is it usually a software, i.e. device driver, responsibility to set up FC credits on PCIe bus? Where could I get familiar with relevant linux API?

Answer (score 1):

**PCIe 3.0** Specification clearly mentions about Credit Consumed , Credit Limit variables implemented as Counters for each enabled Virtual Channel for Flow Control mechanism.

However you can enable or disable a particular VC through software(Writing to dedicated register in configuration Space). So Flow control mechanism is totally handled by dedicated hardware in PCIe.

Answer (score 0):

The credit based flow control is build in hardware.

Comment: I don't argue this, but what provides the relevant settings for credit based FC? Is it a software, or the hardware determines it?

Comment: The credits are calculated based on FIFO sizes. A transmitter knows the space in the receiver. If he sends a packet, he must decrement the credit score. When the receiver processed the packet and the FIFO is emptied, the receicer sends a flow control packet to update/increment the credits again. All calculation algorithms are defined in the PCIe standard. I don't know any changeable parameters for a software API. If I remember correctly, there is an initial credit exchange after link initialization.